# React gives an error about a page while I'm on another

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I got a two pages app. Links to these pages are;

```
class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <div className="container text-center logo-con">
                    <Link to="/">
                        <Image src={logo} width="223" height="67" alt="None" id="logo"/>
                    </Link>
                    <Link to="/demo" className="pull-right a-demo">Demo Talep</Link>
                </div>

        );
    }
}
```

And here s my router to these pages;

```
        <Router>
           <div>
               <Header/>
               <Route exact path="/" component={MainTab}/>
               <Route path="/demo" component={Form}/>
               <Footer/>
           </div>
        </Router>
```

MainTab component has 3 tabs and one of them has a handleScroll() function which I use to add navbar-fixed-top class to nav.
The problem is while I'm on /demo page which has nothing to do with this handlescroll() function, I'm gettin this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/kalen/WebstormProjects/akillisepet/src/components/partials/properties.js:10
   7 | handleScroll(){
   8 |    window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
   9 |        let fixedNav = document.getElementById('navbarToFixed');
> 10 |        let fixedNavTop = fixedNav.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  11 |        let scrolltop = window.pageYOffset;
  12 |        if(scrolltop > fixedNavTop){
  13 |            fixedNav.classList.add('navbar-fixed-top');
```

My question is while I'm on another page why this function tryin to be executed?
How can I fix that problem ? Thank you

Here 's my handleScroll() function. How should I change it?

```
handleScroll(){
       window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
           let fixedNav = document.getElementById('navbarToFixed');
           let fixedNavTop = fixedNav.getBoundingClientRect().top;
           let scrolltop = window.pageYOffset;
           if(scrolltop > fixedNavTop){
               fixedNav.classList.add('navbar-fixed-top');
           }else{
               fixedNav.classList.remove('navbar-fixed-top');
           }
       });
    }


    componentDidMount(){
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll.bind(this));
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll.bind(this));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be due to not properly setting up / clearing your `'scroll'` event listener.

The set up of event listeners should be executed in a one time lifecycle function such as [`componentDidMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

```
componentDidMount() {

  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
}
```

and cleared in a one time lifecycle function such as [`componentWillUnmount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount):

```
componentWillUnmount() {

  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
}
```

You might also want to nest your listener's logic within a [`try .. catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) statement such as the following to prevent such errors from propagating throughout your app.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {

  try {

    const fixedNav = document.getElementById('navbarToFixed')

    // FixedNav?
    if (!fixedNav) throw '!FixedNav'

    const fixedNavTop = fixedNav.getBoundingClientRect().top
    const scrolltop = window.pageYOffset

    if(scrolltop > fixedNavTop){

      fixedNav.classList.add('navbar-fixed-top')
    }

  } catch (error) {

    // Handle Error.
    console.log(error)
  }
})
```

Comment: I added try..catch statement to function and it seems worked ty.